# File to hold 500 random numbers ranging from 0 to 1000. Writes these numbers to the file then open the file and read the numbers one by one

Tags: java, arrays, file, loops, random

Finding difficulty in the while loop. I am unsure how to begin calling and/or reading each number in the generated file so that I can determine the smallest and largest number, as well as the sum. Also if possible could someone explain how write code so that if any of the numbers are consecutive it counts how many times.

```
PrintWriter prw = new PrintWriter("results.txt");
int num, largest, smallest, total = 0, count = 0;
int programnumber = 6;
    double average = 0;

PrintWriter prw1= new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("randomdata.txt"));
Random generator = new Random(); 
for (int i = 0; i < 1001; i++){     
         num = generator.nextInt(500);      //Will this generate a file w/ 500 num?
         prw1.write(num + "\n");
    }
    prw1.close();

    largest = 0;        
    smallest = 9999;        
    while (prw1.nextInt()){            //what call statement do I use? 
            num = (prw1.nextInt());    //unsure how to begin reading numbers
            if (num > largest){
                largest = num;
            }
            if (num < smallest){
                smallest = num;
            }
    total += num;
    count++; 
        }
    average = (total / total);
```

Comment: You should use camel case for your variables -- programNumber, randomData.txt etc...

Comment: Also your loop adds 1001 numbers, not just 500 per your comment with a question mark.  Remember java is 0 based...so < 1000 is 0-999 or 1000 numbers ;)

Comment: Thank you. I'm particularly struggling though with creating the file and also calling/reading each number from the file separately using a while loop to determine the max and min.

Comment: @matthewcrandall I will suggest to consider one part at a time. 1. First try to generate random number that you need. 2. Then store them in file. 3. Open file using scanner class. Just do some googling will will tons of examples for these.

Answer (score 1):

```
num = generator.nextInt(500);      //Will this generate a file w/ 500 num?
```

What the above does is to generate a random value between 0 and 499

In order for you to read from the file you will have to either use `BufferedReader`, `Scanner`, `FileReader` or any other reader and not use `PrintWriter` since it's used to write, not to read.

So you can try this. First create a reader:

```
Scanner scr = new Scanner(fileToRead); //fileToRead should be the file you wrote
```

Then replace the following:

```
while (prw1.nextInt()){            //what call statement do I use? 
    num = (prw1.nextInt());    //unsure how to begin reading numbers
    // ...
}
```

with this:

```
while(scr.hasNextLine()){
    num = Integer.parseInt(scr.nextLine());
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `nextInt` does what you think it does. You write:

```
num = generator.nextInt(500); //Will this generate a file w/ 500 num?
```

The answer to that question is **no**. According to [the `Random` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29):

> ```
> public int nextInt(int n)
> ```
>
> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly
>   distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value
>   (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

So `nextInt(500)` generates a number between 0 and 499 (inclusive).

Instead, you'll want to use `nextInt(1000 + 1)` to get numbers from 0 to 1000, inclusive.

You should also change your reading code. You're trying to read from an output stream, which you can't do. You could change the code to work with a scanner, but I would personally use a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html):

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("randomdata.txt"));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        // Do something, e.g. Integer.parseInt(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
} catch (IOException ie) {
    ie.printStackTrace();
}
```

One reason to use `BufferedReader` instead of `Scanner` is that it's extensible to different formats of data. Maybe before each number in the line you had a prefix, or you had two numbers in a line. You could use `BufferedReader` to grab the whole line, then format the string before parsing it. With `Scanner`, a call to `nextInt` on `"Number: 6"` wouldn't work out well.

Comment: 1. Your while loop will never terminate providing first line is not null. 2. While saving ints to file you need to provide some space. 3. Scanner class for reading the file will suits better for this situation.

Comment: @Smit: thanks for the comment; forgot to assign the result of `nextLine`. What do you mean by providing space with saving `int`s to a file? I haven't done anything with writing in my example. Also, I generally use `BufferedReader`s instead of `Scanner`s; could you explain why a `Scanner` would "suit ... better for this situation"?

Comment: Well while saving file you need to provide some delimiter other wise everything will get merge together. Scanner will suit as scanner class has method `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` where  which will avoid parsing.

Comment: I wrote my code to match the original poster's code. In the question, he uses the delimiter `"\n"` so I used a `BufferedReader` to read each line. I didn't modify any writing code; I just used the delimiter that he provided.